# Clustering of sentences

Tags: java, machine-learning

I need to know about some good techniques to do analysis on data relatiing to word similarity. I want to know similarity algorithms compared with categorization techniques to get the best clustering solutions.

Comment: This question is far far too broad for Stack Overflow... What sort of answers are you expecting? The dump of knowledge about these things could span thousands of pages. First try google, then when you get stuck, make a question specific to the exact data you are dealing with.

Comment: I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this site:
http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/10/ir-math-in-java-experiments-in.html#ga

This would help you out with different algos and you can come up with the best as per your requirements.